# Pip not activated properly when using venv in Jenkins

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, pip, python-venv

I am using Jenkins running on a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Rasbian). On this Jenkins instance, I want to run Python (3.6) in a virtual env, using `venv`. However when i run my script (using Jenkins Execute-shell build-step) and activate `pip`, it does not work properly and I am not able to use the installed modules. Running the exact same script in the terminal works perfectly, and I can use the module.

I have tried to find the issue, and it seems like the `pip` in the `venv` is not used when I run the script through Jenkins.

In jenkins I have added the following after the `venv` has been installed and activated to try to debug it. Workspace is located in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test Python VENV/`:

```
>python --version
Python 3.6.5
>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
>which python
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test Python VENV/venv/bin/python
>which pip
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test Python VENV/venv/bin/pip
>pip install coverage
Collecting coverage
Installing collected packages: coverage
Successfully installed coverage-4.5.3
>pip show coverage | grep Location     
Location: /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>python -m coverage --version
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test Python VENV/venv/bin/python: No module named coverage
```

However if I run the same script in a terminal (i.e. outside Jenkins) it works and i get the following (directory is `~Develop/python_test/`):

```
>python --version
Python 3.6.5
>pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /home/pi/Develop/python_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
>which python
/home/pi/Develop/python_test/venv/bin/python
>which pip
/home/pi/Develop/python_test/venv/bin/pip
>pip install coverage
Collecting coverage
Installing collected packages: coverage
Successfully installed coverage-4.5.3
>pip show coverage | grep Location
Location: /home/pi/Develop/python_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>python -m coverage --version
Coverage.py, version 4.5.3 with C extension
```

So my problem is that when I run this through Jenkins, the Pip in the venv is does not seem to be used, instead the systems default Pip is used. And for some reason `pip --version` and `which pip` shows two different paths in Jenkins.

The full script that I am running (both in Jenkins and in the terminal) can be found below:

```
echo Creating and activating virtual environment
python="python3.6"
venv_name="venv"

echo VERSIONS BEFORE VENV
python --version
pip --version
which python
which pip

echo 'Creating venv'
$python -m venv $venv_name
echo 'Activating venv'
. $venv_name/bin/activate

echo VERSIONS AFTER VENV
python --version
pip --version
which python
which pip

pip install coverage
pip show coverage | grep Location
python -m coverage --version
```

Comment: You may have a global pip configuration (or environment variables affecting pip) in effect. Also, does `python -m pip` within the venv have the same effect?

Comment: @AKX: `python -m pip` does not seem to be the same pip as just `pip`. `python -m pip` points to the `pip` inside my `env`. If I change from `pip` to `python -m pip` in my script it seems to be working. Do you know what might cause this? I have pip (connected to python 2.7) in my PATH/environment variable, but I thought that would be no problem an that `pip` would be redirected to `pip` inside my `venv` as soon as I activated it, but is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Pyenv Jenkins PLugin [Pyenv](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pyenv+Pipeline+Plugin)

I tested your script and it seems to work, just add `#!/bin/bash` shebang.